# Tableau Dashboard Date Relationship

Tags: tableau-api

I am working on the tableau dashboard where I am using two different data sources, and both of them have their dashboard. Now, I am trying show both of those dashboards on one dashboard by creating a relationship between both of my data sources so that I have standard filters which can filter both of my dashboard on the executive dashboard.

However, the problem I am facing is that I cannot create a relationship for month filter. For example, in Data Source A have a monthly column in the database (Jan, Feb, March....Dec), and Data source B does not have month column;
however, I have created a 'Date Range' parameter which can filter out the Data source B dashboard with different month selections

I am having trouble connecting their relationship so that I can have only one month filter which can filter both my dashboards and gives me the result for the month I am looking, for example (Jan or Feb or any other month). Can anyone help me with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the same parameter you are using on Datasource B to filter records in Datasource A.

You could created a calculated field that returns a True or False based upon whether or not your Date Month equals the parameter month.  It depends on your date field format, but something like:

```
[date_parameter] = DATENAME('month',[date_field])
```